# Does ftruncate() copy data if I truncate to a larger size than original?

Tags: linux, file, unix, filesystems

From the description at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/ftruncate.html, it is not very clear how ftruncate works.

If suppose, I truncated a file to 1GB, followed by a truncation to 2GB. In case ftruncate does not find extra 1GB of space right after the old 1GB, does it copy the data to a new place to keep the file contiguous?

Comment: The `ftruncate` function just asks the filesystem to change the size of the file. How the file system does that completely depends on that file system. A network file system will do that completely differently from the way an in-memory file system would do it, which will do it completely different from the way a disk-based file system would.

Answer (score 2):

#### No

The files are not contiguous to start with. A tree-structured block map is used, so it's only necessary to add more blocks to the map.

Also, while this is not *required* by Posix, all real Unix-like systems support [*sparse files*,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_file) so mostly it only needs to increase the length and not actually add blocks at all. A later read will notice (inside the kernel) the lack of backing blocks and the kernel will know to just return zeroes.  A later write to the un-backed area will naturally need to finally start allocating blocks.

Comment: I think the second paragraph is the right answer here. The first paragraph is not necessarily true for all file system types (xfs, btrfs, ext[34], jfs, [v]fat, etc...). Also, I think, on file systems like [v]fat that don't support sparse files, `ftruncate()` is required to either zero-fill or return an error...

Comment: @twalberg, you are technically correct, of course, but consider the context of SO and in particular a question specifically tagged with *both* linux and unix. I think it's reasonable to accurately generalize about native ffs/extN filesystems.

Comment: In an enterprise environment, I can quite easily point to different Linux systems, some running entirely XFS file systems, some running entirely reiserfs, some starting to play with btrfs, and yet others that, due to dual-boot requirements, have native vfat partitions. The OP didn't say anything about the particular configuration involved, so I just wanted to note that there may not be a one-size-fits-all answer...

Answer (score 1):

The filesystem provides indirection over block devices, block devices can have layers and indirection too.  Disks provide indirection as well.

Indeed, the files are not necessarily contiguous before the first `ftruncate`.

If it's your goal to keep the data contiguous, you can try filesystem-specific tweaks during the `mkfs` or `mount`.  Also, instead of `ftruncate` you could try `fallocate` (or `posix_fallocate`).